# How to convert CSV datas in <pre> into HTML table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, html-table, pre

I have a HTML file.
It has **Pre-formatted text** with CSV data in it.

```
<pre>1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,0,1,2
3,4,5,6
</pre>
```

How to extract this data and convert it into a HTML table using Javascript?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: jQuery at all needed?

Comment: @ParthThakkar No..Jquery is not allowed.Only Javascript.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks for your editing.Can you Help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the function described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293163/377628). It returns an array if you give it CSV data. So given the data:

```
<pre id="CSV_DATA">1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,0,1,2
3,4,5,6
</pre>
```

You can get the CSV into a Javascript string:

```
var csv_data = document.getElementById("CSV_DATA").innerHTML;
```

Then use the function `CSVToArray` to get an array of the data:

```
var array_data = CSVToArray(csv_data, ",");
```

Then make an HTML table:

```
var table=document.createElement('table');
table.border='1';
document.body.appendChild(table);
for(var i=0; i<array_data.length; i++){
    var line = array_data[i];
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0; j<line.length; j++){
        var td=document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = line[j];
        tr.appendChild(td);
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code. Please review it and work out the details. But what it's supposed to do is iterate through the array returned by `CSVToArray` and add each element of that array to a table row, then add each generated row to a table. The table is added to the document's body, but you can add it wherever you please.

And here's [a demo of mine as well](http://jsfiddle.net/E52gj/).

Comment: Great answer, just used it in my app. Works great :-) +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the data is going to be in the exact format you gave, then something simple like this will work:

**Markup**:

```
<pre id="data">1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,0,1,2
3,4,5,6</pre>
<div id="table"></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var table = '';
var rows = new Array();

rows = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML.split('\n');
table += '<table>'

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var columns = rows[i].split(',');
    table += '<tr>';

    for(var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        table += '<td>' + columns[j] + '</td>';
    }

    table += '</tr>';
}

table += '</table>';
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = table;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SxAHe/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked for me. But, I need a simple alteration for it. I want borders around each cell. I will be very grateful if you help me with this one. Thank you.

Comment: @bharath119 You can use some CSS. Here is Jia's solution with some CSS added: http://jsfiddle.net/UPsjZ/.